# Run tor and TBB at the same time with the same ports on same PC

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, relays

Just what the title says: is it safe/good practise/etc to run tor as a service (LM17.2) *and* TBB on the same PC, same time, same ports? Will this be related to that part of the FAQ where it says I have better chance at anonymity due to the "mingling" of the traffic?

Alternative: would using tor and TBB with different ports but at the same time (same computer) be an extra security as the same part in the FAQ says?

The thing that bothers me most is how does this (do these two) affect this:

> [...] if an attacker can watch all of your incoming and outgoing traffic, then it's easy for him to learn which connections were relayed and which started at you.

This "attacker" here sounds like my ISP...

Comment: No two processes can listen to the same port on the same interface.